# Is there a term for horses with white inside the legs?

Tags: single-word-requests, animals

More specifically than the question title: Is there any traditional word in English for the color pattern of a black horse with white on the inside of the legs?  I mean just the inside, so it is not coronet, socks, or stockings.

I have searched "horse colors," and "horse markings" online and found several horse sites and related Wikipedia articles.  They have no such terms.

I am asking because I want a translation of a Classical Chinese term which a dictionary written around 100 CE defined as a black horse with white thighs.  And this was traditionally interpreted as meaning inner thighs.

Comment: I think [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a better place tot ask this.

Comment: Where have you looked? This is probably too specialized for ELU.

Comment: Unusual leg markings.

Comment: *”Horses may have isolated body spots that are not large or numerous enough to qualify them as an Appaloosa, Pinto or Paint. Such markings are usually simply called "body spots," sometimes identified by location, i.e. "belly spot," "flank spot," etc. When this type of isolated spotting occurs, it usually involves sabino genetics.*” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse_markings